# C# .NET ManagementObjectSearcher Query

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

My C# .NET 2.0 application performs two queries using the `ManagementObjectSearcher` class:

```
_searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSWmi_PnPInstanceNames");

_searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");
```

I would like to combine them, so that `_searcher` contains all the results from both queries.  However, when I try to do this...

```
_searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSWmi_PnPInstanceNames AND MSSerial_PortName");
```

...an "Invalid query" exception is thrown.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can make this work?  Thanks.

Comment: That wouldn't be a sane way to write a query in any SQL dialect I can think of. If the `select` statements return the same rowtype, you could try running a `union` of the two selects (don't know if this would work with wmi though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unfortunately, the WMI query language does not support `join` or `union` operations,** so you have to run these queries separately (since the select from different object stores).

The WMI Query Language (WQL) is a subset of ANSI SQL — with some semantic changes. Not everything you can do in SQL is possible in WQL. You can see the WMI [supported query constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) online at MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run query with multiple tables as shown below

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher; 
 query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("Select SMS_CollectToSubCollect.subCollectionID,SMS_Collection.Name " +
                                        " from SMS_CollectToSubCollect, SMS_Collection " +
                                        " where  subCollectionID in " +
                                        " (select CollectionID  from SMS_Collection where name='{0}') " +
                                        " and SMS_Collection.CollectionID  =  SMS_CollectToSubCollect.parentCollectionID " , name));
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
//TODO:read values from results 
 }
```

Hope this helps